# Basic Geometry Sum

Tags: geometry

Suppose P,Q,R and S are the midpoints of the sides AB,BC,CD and DA, respectively of a rectangle ABCD. If the area of the rectangle is delta, then area of the figure bounded by straight lines AQ,BR,CS and DP is?
Please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $AQ\cap DP=\{L\}$, $AQ\cap BR=\{M\}$, $CS\cap DP=\{K\}$ and $CS\cap BR=\{N\}$.

Since $AQCS$ and $DPBR$ are parallelograms, we see that $KLMN$ is parallelogram.

Now, let $F$ is a middle point of $RC$.

Thus, $QF||BR$, which says that $G$ is a middle point of $NC$, where $\{G\}=QF\cap NC$.

In another hand, since $R$ is a middle point of $DC$ and $RB||DP$, we obtain that $N$ is a middle point of $KC$.

By the same way we can get that $AL=LM=KN=NC$ and $DK=KL=BM=MN$

and since $AQ=CS$ and $DP=BR$, we obtain $SK=MR$ and $PL=RN$.

Now, since $NG=GC$ and $MNGQ$ is parallelogram we obtain that $S_{\Delta GQC}=\frac{1}{3}S_{MNCQ}.$

But $GC=GN=MN=SK$, which says that $GC=\frac{1}{5}CS$ and $S_{\Delta GQC}=\frac{1}{10}S_{AQCS}$.

Hence, $S_{MQCN}=\frac{3}{10}S_{AQCS}$.

By the same way we can get that $S_{ALKS}=\frac{3}{10}S_{AQCS}$, which says that 
$$S_{KLMN}=S_{AQCS}-2\cdot\frac{3}{10}S_{AQCS}=\frac{2}{5}S_{AQCS}=\frac{\Delta}{5}$$
and we are done!